# Extracting HOG features using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new in OpenCV. Previously I used Matlab to compute HOG features from an image of 9x9 pixels. In Matlab I was getting feature vector of 9 values as I was using 9 bin histogram. But in OpenCV, first problem is that I am unable to run:

```
d.compute(imROI, descriptorsValues,Size(9,9),Size(0,0),locs);
```

It seems 9x9 image is less than minimum allowed size, is it true?

Secondly, can some one please explain me all the input parameters of:

```
compute(const Mat& img, vector<float>& descriptors,
         Size winStride, Size padding,
         const vector<Point>& locations) const
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

### It seems 9x9 image is less than minimum allowed size, is it true?

**It's not true.**

For [`compute`](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html), the third parameter is `Size winStride`, you can use smaller values up to `Size(1,1)`.

I guess you didn't initialize `HOGDescriptor hog` correctly that caused you not able to run.

---

### If you want to only get 8 values for Size of imROI is 9x9?

The size of hog features can be computed as

```
num_of_hog_features = (size_t)nbins * ( blockSize.width/cellSize.width) 
                         * (blockSize.height/cellSize.height) * ((winSize.width 
                         - blockSize.width)/blockStride.width + 1) 
                         * ((winSize.height - blockSize.height)
                         / blockStride.height + 1);
```

So in order to get `8` values of hog feature, you can setup the parameters as follows:

```
HOGDescriptor *hog=new HOGDescriptor(cvSize(9,9),cvSize(9,9),
                                     cvSize(9,9),cvSize(9,9),8);
vector<float> descriptors;
hog->compute(imROI, descriptors,Size(1,1), Size(0,0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please write me full statement that extracts HOG from 9x9 image with 8 bin histogram. I expect to get 8 values in feature vector (HoG feature)

Comment: @user3319734 If you want to only get 8 values, set the values accordingly based on the above equation.

Comment: Size of imROI is 9x9 and my running this:              d.compute(imROI, descriptorsValues,Size(32,32)); (getting 3780 dimensional feature vector).  If I reduce the size further then program generates error. I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot  !!! could you please explain me what this statement do: HOGDescriptor *hog=new HOGDescriptor(cvSize(9,9),cvSize(9,9),
                                     cvSize(9,9),cvSize(9,9),8);

Comment: @user3319734 For the parameters of `HOGDescriptor`, please refer to [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#gpu-hogdescriptor-hogdescriptor).

Comment: Thanks once again ... sorry to bother you again, could you please let me know how to access features vector? Like when we run hog.compute(imROI, descriptors,Size(1,1), Size(0,0)); we get features but how to access them?

Comment: @user3319734 Use `descriptors[i]` to access its `i-1`th value.

Comment: so for all bins do I need to do something like  descriptors[1:8]?

Comment: @user3319734 Yes, if you mean `descriptors[0]...descriptors[7]`.

Comment: Actually I need to save all these 8 value in a row , so that I can write a file for later classification.

Comment: @user3319734 They are already in a row: `vector<float> descriptors;`.

Comment: Thanks .. how to show them? cout<<vector<float> descriptors; doesn't work.